# React-bootstrap carousel styles don't applying

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, react-bootstrap

I have installed react-bootstrap with:

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

command, and successfully imported it:

```
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel'
<Carousel>
...
</Carousel>
```

but it's styles didn't applied!
What I need to do to use it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-Bootstrap doesn't come with bootstrap CSS automatically - it only produces the corresponding `div` elements with classes.

If you're using css modules, import the bootstrap css in `index.js`:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

If you're using normal HTML, include `bootstrap.min.css` in your html file somehow.